# Is it possible to print pdf Url data content with StarPRNT-SDK-iOS-Swift ? Or is there any other method to print the data from remote(api response)?

Tags: ios, swift5, printers, thermal-printer, posprinter

I'm following git demo sample for integration : git : https://github.com/star-micronics/StarPRNT-SDK-iOS-Swift
I have successfully installed the sdk and am able to print samples in class EnglishReceiptsImpl.

Now, I'm trying to print the content I'm getting in api response.

I'm concerned about :

1. Is there any direct method to convert/pass a pdf url to print the content?
2. How to pass data(Data/NSData) to print in "command".

I'm using/ working for **TSP650II** printer model.

The pods I have installed are:

// Pods for Swift SDK

```
 pod 'StarIO', '2.8.2'

  pod 'StarIO_Extension', '1.15.0'
```

Here is my code :

> In class SearchPortViewController

```
    func openStarPrinter() {
        var commands: Data

        let localizeReceipts: ILocalizeReceipts = LocalizeReceipts.createLocalizeReceipts(AppDelegate.getSelectedLanguage(), paperSizeIndex: .threeInch)
//        commands = PrinterFunctions.createTextReceiptData(emulation, localizeReceipts: localizeReceipts, utf8: false)

        // Method (trying to print data from pdf url) : (createPdf417Data)

        commands = ApiFunctions.createPdf417Data(emulation)

        GlobalQueueManager.shared.serialQueue.async {
            _ = Communication.sendCommands(commands,

                                           portName: self.portName,

                                           portSettings: self.portSettings,

                                           timeout: 10000,  // 10000mS!!!

                                           completionHandler: { (communicationResult: CommunicationResult) in

                                            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                                                self.showSimpleAlert(title: "Communication Result",message: Communication.getCommunicationResultMessage(communicationResult),buttonTitle: "OK",buttonStyle: .cancel)

                                           //     self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)

                                            }

            })

        }

    }
```

> Where in class ApiFunctions

```
let  globalPdfUrl:URL? = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "fake-store-receipt", withExtension: "pdf")


static func createPdf417Data(_ emulation: StarIoExtEmulation) -> Data {
   
    let otherData = try! Data(contentsOf: globalPdfUrl!)
    
    let builder: ISCBBuilder = StarIoExt.createCommandBuilder(emulation)
    
    builder.beginDocument()
    builder.appendPdf417Data(withAbsolutePosition: otherData, line: 0, column: 1, level: SCBPdf417Level.ECC0, module: 2, aspect: 2, position: 1)
    builder.endDocument()
    
    return builder.commands.copy() as! Data
}
```

**But the print is not in the correct format.**

[image]

Hoping for quick and detailed solution!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you resolve this problem?

Comment: @hopsey yes I have.